# Can't connect to GitHub Package Registry from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, github, nuget, nuget-package, github-package-registry

In Visual Studio 2019, I'm trying to connect to our private GitHub Package Registry but keep getting unauhorized error.

Here's what I've done:

1. Created a Personal Access Token (PAT) on GitHub with `Write` access to packages.
2. I then created a `nuget.config` file with following code and placed it in `c:\Users\My_User_Name\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\` folder.
3. I also tried placing this `nuget.config` file in the project root

I still get unauthorized error when I try to connect to our GitHub Package Registry. Any idea what the problem is?

Here's the `nuget.config` file contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="Our Corporate GitHub Packages" value="https://nuget.pkg.github.com/OUR_CORPORATE_ACCOUNT_ON_GITHUB/index.json" />
    <add key="Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <github>
      <add key="Username" value="MY_GITHUB_USERNAME" />
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="MY_GITHUB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN" />
    </github>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Answer (score -1):

Although the settings in Nuget.config file will normally be reflected/shown in VS’s NuGet Package Manager – Package Source settings, please kindly try to add the package sources manually in VS > Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > Package Sources and see if VS will prompt a dialog to ask for entering username and password when using this package source.(remember to click `Update` after adding the new package source)

Besides, please kindly check again if other permissions are needed, not very sure, but for example "[read](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/learn-github-packages/about-permissions-for-github-packages#about-scopes-and-permissions-for-package-registries)", and please try to add other permissions, if possible.

BTW, remember to restart VS as sometimes changes may not be refreshed quickly.